# Retrive acf fields in publish_post action for wp_mail

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, wp-mail

I have a custom post type called "Envios". In it I've created a Custom Meta box which allows to select users and posts. When one of this custom post types is published it sends an email to the selected users with the content of the selected posts.
To select the posts I use the ACF plugin, with the field Post Object.

The issue is that sometimes the emails are sent properly but in most cases nothing is delivered.

Here is the code:

```
    // Adds Custom Meta Box
    function email_delivery_munda_add_custom_box() {
        $screens = ['envios', 'md_cpt'];
        foreach ($screens as $screen) {
            add_meta_box(
                'md_email_delivery_box_id',           // Unique ID
                'Detalles de email',                  // Box title
                'md_email_delivery_custom_box_html',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
                $screen,                              // Post type
                'side',
                'default'
            );
        }
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'email_delivery_munda_add_custom_box');

    // Adds the content of the Custom Meta Box
    function md_email_delivery_custom_box_html($post)
    {

        $asunto = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email_delivery_asunto', true);

        wp_nonce_field( 'save_md_email', 'md_email_nonce' );

        if ($asunto == "") {
            $asunto = "Informe - " . date("d-m-Y");
        }
        ?>
        <div class="email-delivery-asunto">
          <label for="email_delivery_asunto">Asunto</label>
          <input type="text" name="email_delivery_asunto" id="email_delivery_asunto" class="postbox"  value=" <?php echo $asunto ?>" placeholder="Informe - <?php echo date("d-m-Y") ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="email-delivery-receptores">
            <label for="select-emails">Destinatarios</label>
            <?php
            $blogusers = get_users();
            // Array of WP_User objects.
            echo '<select name="clients-email-input[]" id="select-emails" class="admin-email-receptores" multiple="multiple"><option></option>';
            foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
              echo '<option value="'. esc_html( $user->user_email ) .'">' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php $enviados = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email_send', true); ?>

        <div class="email-delivery-asunto">
          <label for="email_send">Ultimo envio</label>
          <p id="email_send"><?php echo $enviados ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php

    }

    // Saves post data
    function md_email_save_postdata($post_id) {

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['md_email_nonce'] ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['md_email_nonce'], 'save_md_email' ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        $asunto = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email_delivery_asunto'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email_delivery_asunto', $asunto );

    }
    add_action('save_post', 'md_email_save_postdata');


    // Sends an email when custom post type Envios is published
    function md_email_publish_postdata($post_id) {

        $asunto = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email_delivery_asunto'] );

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
        );

        $enviados = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email_send'] );
        $blogusers = get_users();

        foreach ($_REQUEST['clients-email-input'] as $selectedOption) {
          array_push($headers, "BCC:" . $selectedOption);

          foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
            if ($user->user_email === $selectedOption) {
                $enviados .= "<b>" . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . "</b> " . esc_html( $user->user_email) . "<br>";
            }
          }

        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email_send', $enviados );

        $content = '';

        // Removing from here makes it work.
        $posts = get_field('casos',$post_id);

        if( $posts ): ?>
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
                <?php setup_postdata($post);

                $content .= '<h1>' . get_the_title( $post ) . '</h1><br>';
                $content .= '<p>' . get_field( 'descripcion_breve', $post) . '</p><br>';

            endforeach; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
        <?php endif;
        // until here.


        $clients_list = "xxxxxxxx@email.com";

        wp_mail( $clients_list, $asunto , $content, $headers );

    }
    add_action('publish_envios', 'md_email_publish_postdata', 10, 2 );
```

IF I remove the ACF part from **// Removing from here makes it work.** to **// until here.** the emails are sent okay every time but without the selected posts content.

I can't really tell which is the problem, but maybe you can impart some wisdom on the matter.
Thanks in advance!

---

**SOLUTION:**

ACF use the action acf/save_post AFTER the post is published, so I was trying to get a value that wasn't there yet.
So I changed the action to the acf save_post and between it I use `if (get_post_status($post_id) == 'publish') {` to check the status of the post.

Furthermore I update the Object Post output as follows:

```
  $posts = get_field( 'casos', $post_id );

    if( $posts ):
        foreach( $posts as $post):

            $content .= '<h1>' . get_the_title( $post ) . '</h1><br>';

            if ( get_field( 'descripcion_breve', $post->ID )) {
                $content .= '<p>' . get_field( 'descripcion_breve', $post->ID ) . '</p><br>';
            } else {
                $content .= '<p>Description empty</p><br>';
            }

        endforeach;
    endif;
```

Comment: `setup_postdata` and `wp_reset_postdata` are for front-end queries, they won't work reliably (or at all) on most admin pages.

Comment: `ACF use the action acf/save_post AFTER the post is published` - that is not entirely correct, it depends on the priority given. If the priority is less than 10, then it is called **before** the post save, but if it is greater than 10, it is called **after** the post is saved. Check the [official documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...Removed my prior 'solutions'...

---

So, the real problem  here is that this function is hooked to `publish_post` action, at which point the post might not be saved yet, if it is a new post. Only if it is a post already saved but with some other status, we can access the ACF values using `get_field()`.

Solution could be to use a hook [`acf/save_post`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) with priority of 10 or larger, since it fires after the post has been saved, therefore allowing us to get the values using `get_field()`.

This is a short example of usage of this hook:

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // bail if wrong post type
    if( get_post_type( $post_id ) !== 'envios' ) {
         return;
    }

    // get new value
    $posts = get_field( 'casos', $post_id );


    // do something

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

Comment: My friend, thanks a lot for the help,
The issue remains but the results are:

-With the first option the email is sent, but it fails to get the values from the ACF fields, $content value remains empty (or ' ' ). One thing I tested is what happens if I update the value $content just after " if( $posts ): " and the value doesn't update either so I'm not connecting properly with the object post field, can't say why though..

-On the second option the email is not delivered at all.

Comment: I've tried debugging as you suggested, on debug.log I found an error with a line of code higher yet after solving it the results were the same and I didn't get any other error.

I'm going to keep testing and maybe try to reach the ACF people for help in the matter.
Again, thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: @NicolasLandgraf I updated my second option, function `get_field()` does not accept the post object, but only the post ID. Also, there is yet another option for debugging we can try. Write this line `var_dump( get_field( 'casos', $post_id ) ); die;` somewhere inside your function. Hopefully, that will output either the posts array, or the error.

Comment: I've added `var_dump( get_field( 'casos', $post_id ) ); die;` as you asked, I put it inside the publish_envios add action.
When I publish the post the whole page goes white and It says "NULL". I guess it means that the array of post objects always returns empty.
As I'm testing this inside the admin pages I'm using almost the same code in single_envios.php and the values appear okay (just to be sure that I'm not writing the wrong field name and such things). The only difference between codes is that in single_envios.php I output `$content` with `echo $content;`
Same result with both options.

Comment: My friend, i think I figured out the issue, I'm currently testing but I guess that's it.

ACF use the action acf/save_post AFTER the post is published, so I was trying to get a value that wasn't there yet.
So I changed the action to the acf save_post and between it I use `if (get_post_status($post_id) == 'publish') {` to check the status of the post.
My guess is that it sometimes worked because I might have publish a post - then change to draft and publish it again, sending the old values. So my former questions where misleading, but debugging with your ideas was the key!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NicolasLandgraf I am very glad we came to some conclusion here. Somehow I completely overlooked which action hook were you using, even though you plainly stated it in the question title. :) Anyway, I updated my answer, I believe you will find it as a complete solution now.

Comment: thanks a lot, a I've checked out the update, all I can say, thinks are working smoothly. Glad you came to save me and taught me a few things. =D